# How to skip case sensitive in SQL Json_Value function

Tags: sql, json

I have used **"JSON_VALUE"** function in SQL Query.It works fine as per my requirement. I would like to know how to skip case sensitive in json field.Please check my example jsonData

**Json Data: -**

```
{
  "factoryID": "4",
  "yearID": "2",
  "loggedInUserID": "43",
  "pageIndex": "1",
  "pageSize": "10",
  "searchString": "",
  "whereString": ""
}
```

but when I give field name in Camel case in Json_Value ,then its return null.Please advise how to skip case sensitive in **"Json_Value"**

**SQL:-**

```
 set @FactoryID = JSON_VALUE(@JsonData,'$.FactoryID')
set @YearID = JSON_VALUE(@JsonData,'$.YearID')
```

For Json Detail (Array) :-

```
    SELECT          
    JSON_VALUE(A.value,'$.FactoryID')FactoryID,
    JSON_VALUE(A.value,'$.YearID')YearID,
    JSON_VALUE(A.value,'$.CreatedUserID')CreatedUserID,
    JSON_VALUE(A.value,'$.ModifiedUserID')ModifiedUserID,
    JSON_VALUE(A.value,'$.TempID')TempID

FROM OPENJSON(@JsonDetail) as A
```

Comment: Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include .... **and a tag for the DBMS implementation** (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no built-in way to do this. 
But there are a few options available:

1. You can use `OPENJSON` that returns a set of (`key`, `value`, `type`) and work directly with the key/value pairs (though this approach won't work in case the value you need is an object):

   ```
   DECLARE @json VARCHAR(500) = '{
     "factoryID": "4",
     "yearID": "2",
     "loggedInUserID": "43",
     "pageIndex": "1",
     "pageSize": "10",
     "searchString": "",
     "whereString": ""
   }';

   DECLARE @FactoryID INT,
           @YearID INT;

   SELECT @YearID = IIF(LOWER([key]) = 'yearid', [value], @YearID),
          @FactoryID = IIF(LOWER([key]) = 'factoryid', [value], @FactoryID)
   FROM OPENJSON(@json);

   SELECT @YearID AS YearID,
          @FactoryID AS FactoryID;
   ```
2. Another option is to create a [custom CLR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions) to parse JSON in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: How about for Json array.Please check update sql query for json array

Comment: You can use the same approach with IIF/LOWER with an array but will need to use `OUTER APPLY` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73510165/1336651)